# After moving residence, DSL still works with same login and no technician visit?

Tags: adsl, dsl

I have a question about DSL technology:

I recently moved houses, the new address is only about 300m away.
Right between the 2 locations, there's a DSLAM.

Yesterday, I plugged in the router even though I wasn't expecting it to work until a technician came by. But it did work with the same login data.

It's quite possible both houses are served by that same DSLAM, but is that the reason why it works at the new place?? Can someone explain?

Comment: Depends on a lot of things, including your provider. Mist likely the previous owners connection was not shut down and uses the same infrastructure (but not the same copper pair) that yours did.  Also, in some places anyone can get online with a minimal connection, even with a wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

Usually user account details and virtual circuit details are not tied up with the actual port used in the physical connection. Your authentication details will be used to authenticate at [BRAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband_remote_access_server) not at the DSLAM (Layer 2).

Actually, now DSLAMs are not used in most NGN networks and MSAN are used to provide combined POTS,DSL,PON services.